How and where advanced circuit analysis methods are being used
I'm self-studying circuits theory2 (in my country's educational system, this course is called this).
This course mostly covers advanced circuit analysis methods, like systematic methods, graphs and matrices methods, natural frequencies, state space analysis, etc.
But I'm wondering, how and where these methods are being used.
So I can apply them somewhere and learn them.
Or maybe doing a project.
Because one time in the past, I studied most of this course, but I forgot many parts of it simply because I did no project for it and found no usage for it in real life. But this time, I don't want to forget that anymore.

everywhere some of this is used.  You remember by failing then fixing with practice.
